# How to copy the text from a readonly box in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to copy the text from a read only box from a webpage, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.
I tried using this:

```
    TargetElement = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/fieldset/input').getText('value')
```

But this is not a valid attribute apparently. I've also tried this:

```
TargetElement = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/fieldset/input')
print(TargetElement.text)
```

but it just returns blank.

I'm trying to copy the value of the box under the "generar código" button:
https://www.kemxtreme.cl/index.php

Comment: Please supply the html or a link to it

Comment: Just added the link to the post @RKelley

Answer (score 0):

There is a brief moment where the value in this element has 'espere..' and then shows the input desired.  Below is how you can wait until 'espere' is no longer the value and then retrieve the value:

```
waiting_for_value = True

TargetElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#generado')

value = ''

while waiting_for_value:

    value = TargetElement.get_attribute('value')

    if 'espere' not in value:

        waiting_for_value = False
```

You will want to put more code in place to make sure you don't fall into an infinite loop, but this will get what you're looking for.